# Guest OS in Qemu generates too much interrupts on irq4

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, virtualization, qemu, irq

I am facing problem with interrupt in guest OS runing in qemu-2.3.0.
I am loading windriver (Linux kernel-2.6.34.12-grsec) in -nographic mode in Qemu emulator on Ubuntu 14.04 host.

Host details:

```
    >$ uname -a
    >$ Linux my-qemu-host 3.13.0-52-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 4 04:32:59 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

my command line is:

```
    >$ qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -nographic -k en-us -kernel ${KERNEL} -cpu kvm64 -smp 4 -m 1G ${NETCFG} -gdb tcp::1234 -append "console=ttyS0,115200 ip=dhcp root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=${NFSROOT}" -hda /home/hda
```

I am getting following logs in /var/log/kern.log

```
   kernel: serial8250: too much work for irq4
```

I searched to get rid of this but so many people are suggesting to increase PASS_LIMIT in /serial/8250.c file. this workaround is just avoiding error messages in kern.log file.

Any one having idea how to stop or slow down interrupt frequency?

Comment: [See also](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387650).

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you running i.e. what sort of build? It appears that some hefty serial work is going on (which is expected with embedded).

I just googled how to disable the kernel module for the serial8250 to see if that would help and happened upon this:

http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-serial/msg12360.html

Another thought, seeing as windriver (if it's this: http://www.windriver.com/products/linux/) then I wouldn't be shocked if a "serial console" is automatically enabled. This too could drive s/w interrupt watchdogs to blacklist them as the can spam quite a bit of info depending on what they're set to output.

Sorry, it's just totally a random guess, but I'm going by pure experience with embedded serial device fun (MIPS) and (ARM) past experiences with generic distros

Comment: [Above link](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-serial/msg12360.html) is same as i mentioned in question(disable print). I am searching if there is any console configuration available to speed up console I/O baud rate and prevent it to cross PASS_LIMIT which causes interupt. as some other processes(who has subscription for INTR signal ) are waiting on select and those processes are getting INTR signal frequently, it is affecting on other processes performance.

Comment: Can you post a bit of the kern.log before and after the irq4 event? And specifically does this only happen on boot i.e. preventing you to boot entirely and are there any /sbin/getty in the inittab if so, what's the baud at... Another thing to look for serial consoles in /etc/grub.conf